# Debugging Web API application on CodeMirror

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, remote-debugging, codemirror, w3wp

I am currently developing an ERP all in one web application in AngularJS. Client will design, develop ERP modules there.

I am using codeMirror to edit server side C# code to client. Also have intellisense and compile options. But now I want to add remote debugger option. I searched all over the internet but could not find answer to develop a debug adapter for codemirror to connect IIS (w3wp), load symbols, load call stack and maybe watch window...

There is demo for put breakpoint, but no further :)
https://codemirror.net/demo/marker.html